# How can I add a column to a right join select query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a way to add a country code to a database call record based on a phone number column. I have a table with countries and their dialling codes called countries. I can query all records and add the country code after but I need to be able to filter and paginate the results.

I am working with a system I don't have much control over so adding new columns to tables or rewriting large blocks of code isn't really an option. This is what I have to work with.

Countries Table.

| id | name | dialling_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ireland | 353 |
| 2 | America | 1 |

Call Record table.

| id | startdatetime | enddatetime | route_id | phonenumber | duration_seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-12-18 18:51:12 | 2014-12-18 18:52:12 | 23 | 3538700000 | 60 |
| 2 | 2014-12-18 17:41:02 | 2014-12-18 17:43:02 | 43 | 18700000 | 120 |

Routes table.

| id | number | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 1234567890 | 1 |
| 43 | 0987654321 | 1 |

I need to get sum values of duration, total unique phone numbers all grouped by route_id, route_number but now we need to group these results by country_id so we can group callers by country. I use the mysql query below to get sum values of duration, total unique phone numbers all grouped by route_id, route_number. This query was written by another developer a long time ago.

```sql
SELECT 
    phone_number,
    route_number, 
    COUNT(callrecord_id) AS total_calls, 
    SUM(duration_sec) AS total_duration, 
    callrecord_join.route_id
FROM routes
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DATE(a.startdatetime) AS call_date, 
        a.id AS callrecord_id, 
        a.route_id AS route_id, 
        a.phonenumber AS phone_number,
        a.duration_seconds as duration_sec,
        b.inboundnumber AS route_number, 
    FROM callrecord AS a
    INNER JOIN routes AS b ON a.route_id = b.id
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.startdatetime, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2014-12-18' 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(a.startdatetime, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2014-12-18' 
    AND b.isenabled = 1 
) AS callrecord_join ON routes.id = callrecord_join.route_id
GROUP BY route_id, route_number
LIMIT 10 offset 0;
```

I have everything up to adding a country_id in the right join table so I can group by the country_id.

I know I could loop through each country using php and get the results using a where clause, something like the below but I cannot paginate these results or filter them easily.

`WHERE LEFT(a.phonenumber, strlen($dialling_code)) = $dialling_code`

How can I use the countries table to add a column to the join table query with the country id so I can group by route_id, route_number and country_id? Something like the table below.

| id | startdatetime | enddatetime | route_id | phonenumber | duration_seconds | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-12-18 18:51:12 | 2014-12-18 18:52:12 | 23 | 3538700000 | 60 | 1 |
| 2 | 2014-12-18 17:41:02 | 2014-12-18 17:43:02 | 43 | 18700000 | 120 | 2 |

Comment: You would need a partial match, "starts with", as your JOIN criterion, between the dialling_code and the phonenumber. But you won't even know how many digits of the phone number actually constitute the dialing code, I guess ...

Answer (score 0):

The `RIGHT JOIN` from `routes` to `callrecord_join` serves no purpose, as you already have the `INNER JOIN` between `routes` and `callrecord` in the sub-query, which is on the righthand side of the join.

You can use the join you have described -

```
JOIN countries c ON LEFT(a.phonenumber, LENGTH(c.dialling_code)) = c.dialling_code
```

but it will give the same result as:

```
JOIN countries c ON a.phonenumber LIKE CONCAT(c.dialling_code, '%')
```

which should be slightly less expensive.

You should test the join to `countries` to make sure none of your numbers in `callrecord` join to multiple countries. Some international dialling codes are ambiguous, so it depends on which list of dialling codes you are using.

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(c.dialling_code)
FROM callrecord a
JOIN country c ON a.phonenumber LIKE CONCAT(c.dialling_code, '%')
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Obviously, you will need to batch the above query if your dataset is very large.

I hope I am not grossly over-simplifying things, but from what I understand of your question the query is just:

```
SELECT
    r.id AS route_id,
    r.number AS route_number,
    c.name AS country_name,
    SUM(a.duration_seconds) AS total_duration,
    COUNT(a.id) AS total_calls,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.phonenumber) AS unique_numbers
FROM callrecord AS a
JOIN routes AS r ON a.route_id = r.id
JOIN countries c ON a.phonenumber LIKE CONCAT(c.dialling_code, '%')
WHERE a.startdatetime >= '2014-12-18' 
AND a.startdatetime < '2014-12-19'
AND r.isenabled = 1
GROUP BY r.id, r.number, c.name
LIMIT 10 offset 0;
```

Please note the removal of `DATE_FORMAT()` from the `startdatetime` to make these criteria sargable, assuming a suitable index is available.